# Mystery Specialized?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I bought this bike a couple of months ago and have no idea what model/brand it is. When I bought it it had m760 XT derailleurs, a GXP bottom bracket, XT brakes/shifter combo, a Fox F100 rl fork, brake bosses 51mm, quick release, Deore hubs, 26-inch wheels, and a 9 speed cassette. [image] The bike is pretty light weighing in at around 25 lbs.

Any ideas?

Comment: The bike is very different from what it was originally making it hard to say for sure. I'm 95% sure that there has never been a Specialized bike with that decal on the top tube. It could still be a Specialized bike with changed up decals or it could be something else with changed up decals. The closest Specialized bike I found is the P3 - but it's not a match. You may never know what it really is. Does it meet your needs?

Comment: I have seen Specialized kids bikes with that logo, and they do make some high quality kids hardtails. It could be hardrock originally? Definitely been changed!

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a 2010 era (aprox) RockHopper, the 26" wheel version. It's presumably in a 17" or smaller frame as the downtube and top tube are touching (I think there is a gap on the larger frames).

The top tube is straight unlike the Hardrock (which had a curved top tube which creates a smooth curve with the chain stays).

It looks like it has been converted to a 1x9 setup. Originally it would have been a 3x setup. Acctually it looks like most parts have been upgraded and it has gotten a nice paint job. I'd check if you can remove the brake posts on the chain stays (often they can be unscrewed). That would give it an even cleaner look.

That's a great build at 25lbs. I bet it accelerates like a dream.

Here's a pic of a 2010 RockHopper. The angle isn't perfect but you should be able to see the frame similarities.
[image]